# git push gives a separate empty path

Tags: git

I got five files, A, B, C, D, E in directory 1-NeuralNetworks*/Assignment

I pushed A, B, C and D, E in two git pushes. However, Github repo shows this. If I clone the project, everything is fine and all five files are in folder Assignment. What's going on here? very confused. It feels like a feature triggered accidentally.

[image: git push gives a separate empty path]

Comment: Hard to say without showing us your local file structure, git commands you have used and state of your both local and remote repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the difference in those two lines:

```
                            +---------- see CamelCased difference here!
                            |
                            |
line 1: 1-NeuralNetworksDeepLearning/
line 2: 1-NeuralNetworksDeeplearning/Assignment/
```

One has CamelCased `DeepLearning` vs `Deeplearning`

So the files `A` `B` and `C` are in the directory

```
1-NeuralNetworksDeepLearning/
```

BUT

the files `D` and `E` are in the directory

```
1-NeuralNetworksDeeplearning/Assignment/
```

> Note: Some systems don't distinguish about CamelCased filenames!